# Xamarin.iOS bottom view is partly out of viewport until scroll (LargeTitle, SearchBar, ListView and BoxView combo)

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have the following **iOS 13** problem in Xamarin.Forms: 
A portion of a page (the aqua BoxView) is pushed off screen when:

- opening the page
- scrolling to the top (the initial state).

DEMO:
https://github.com/GerhardSchreurs/SearchDemo

[image]

IN DETAIL:

My MainPage contains a StackLayout. The StackLayout hosts a ListView and a BoxView). The page is set to display Large titles. There also is a PageRenderer for the MainPage, which injects a UISearchController/SearchBar.

When I view the results in the simulator, roughly half of the BoxView is not visible after launch. When I scroll, I see the rest of the BoxView, up until I scroll to the top and release (the initial state).

This problem occurs in iOS 13 (no problems in iOS 12).

This problem goes away when:

- I don't inject the searchcontroller
- I set LargeTitleDisplay to never.

However, I don't want to give up on these two, if possible

[image: Screen after launch:]

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    Title="Hello"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
    ios:Page.LargeTitleDisplay="Automatic"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="Search.MainPage"
    x:Name="_rootPage">
    <StackLayout x:Name="_outerLayout">
        <ListView x:Name="_list" BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" HasUnevenRows="True" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> _data;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _data = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
            _list.ItemsSource = _data;
        }
    }
```

**MainPageRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
namespace Search.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class MainPageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer, IUISearchControllerDelegate
    {
        private UISearchController _searchController;

        public override void WillMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent)
        {
            base.WillMoveToParentViewController(parent);
            SetSearchController(parent);
        }

        void SetSearchController(UIViewController parent)
        {
            _searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null);

            _searchController.HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
            _searchController.DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
            _searchController.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;
            _searchController.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
            _searchController.Delegate = this;

            parent.NavigationItem.HidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false;
            parent.NavigationItem.SearchController = _searchController;
        }
    }
}
```

- Is this a Xamarin(.IOS) bug?
- How do I modify my page to get the expected result?

I've tried many things to fix this, including hacking the height of the listView, but I can't find a solution. I might be unaware of iOS specific settings on the listView or SearchBar which might fix this issue.

Comment: Hi , I think it's be affected by Large Title , not sure it is an issue . From shared code , I can not reproduce it in local project . You can share a sample link here , I will check it .

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated that Microsoft is on top of things! I published the code here:
https://github.com/GerhardSchreurs/SearchDemo
Make sure you test with iOS13+ (this does not occur in iOS12)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT and also, please note that this problem might indeed be affected by large title, but does not occur when searchcontroller is not injected. As a a matter of fact, I believe the "stolen" space in the bottom is the height of the searchcontroller.searchbar

Comment: Okey , thanks for sharing sample link . I also have tried in xcode , it seems alos has this problem .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT  Thank you for confirming that the same issue exists in xcode. Do you have a possible workaround?

Comment: No, I try to find a good way to avoid it , however can not . I will continue to find the workaround , if good news will update here .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thank you for investigating! I reported this as a bug and found a workaround for the time being... See updated post.

Comment: Oh, very good ! Thanks for updating ,and you can post it as an answer .Then other people also can see it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This is a Xamarin.iOS bug:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8758

There are problems with the layout when using the SearchBar in the UISearchController / UINavigationController. This should be fixed in a future release.

*Workaround:*

Don't inject the UISearchController in the in the PageRenderer (which I believe should be the correct method), instead simply fall back to a Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar in your PCL/Shared project like this (example):

```
var searchBar = new SearchBar
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.White,
    TextColor = Color.Black,
    _grid.Children.Add(searchBar, 0, 0);
}
```

You will loose some functionality though. (interaction with Large titles and such)